# change legend in chart in report builder

Tags: charts, chart.js, legend, reportbuilder3.0

I want to change the text in the legend on the right side (attach pic)

[image]

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The text is based on the Series Properties.

1. Right-click on the **Series** you want to change on the Chart
   itself.
2. Select **Series Properties**.
3. Select **Legend**.
4. You can change the text in **Custom legend text:**

You will need to do this for each series in your Chart.

Good luck!